# How can I parse a specific key from JSON and map it to a class using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am new to Retrofit and I am trying to fetch a JSON from an API and display it in my RecylerView. But the problem is the JSON I fetched has two keys, namely **result** and **offers** as shown below.

```
{"result":true,"offers":[{"lmd_id":"1285747","store":"box8.in","merchant_homepage":"https:\/\/box8.in\/","offer_text":"Free Chocolava Cake on All Orders","offer_value":"Free","title":"Free Chocolava Cake","description":"This voucher is applicable on All Orders (On minimum order of &#8377;450)","code":"","terms_and_conditions":"","categories":"Food and Beverages,Fast Food","category_array":{"Food and Beverages":["Fast Food"]},"featured":"No","publisher_exclusive":"N","url":"https:\/\/box8.in\/offers","smartLink":"https:\/\/smartlink.linkmydeals.com\/?account_id=18950&network=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbox8.in%2Foffers","image_url":"","type":"Deal","offer":"Freebie","status":"new","start_date":"2023-01-11","end_date":"2023-06-27"}]}
```

What I want is value inside **offers** key, and map it to a class called **Offers** that looks like this:

```
data class Offers (
    val lmd_id: Int,
    val store: String?,
    val merchant_homepage: String?,
    val long_offer: String?,
    val title: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val code: String?,
    val terms_and_conditions: String?,
    val categories: String?,
    val featured: String?,
    val publisher_exclusive: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val smartlink: String?,
    val image_url: String?,
    val type: String?,
    val offer: String?,
    val offer_value: String?,
    val status: String?,
    val start_date: String?,
    val end_date: String?
)
```

But it doesn't seem there is a way to do that and the key called **result** is creating a problem.

**I created an object,**

```
object DealsNetwork {
    fun getRetrofitClient (): Retrofit {
        val gson = GsonBuilder ().setLenient ().create ()
        return Retrofit.Builder ()
            .baseUrl ("https://feed.linkmydeals.com/")
            .addConverterFactory (GsonConverterFactory.create (gson))
            .build ()
    }
}
```

**A service,**

```
interface DealsService {
    @GET("getOffers/?API_KEY=$api_key&incremental=1&format=json")
    suspend fun getOffers (): List<Offers>
}
```

**And finally I called it in my Fragment,**

```
        val dealsService = DealsNetwork.getRetrofitClient ().create (DealsService::class.java)


        CoroutineScope (Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            // Get list of offers
            val offers = dealsService.getOffers ()

            // Do something with the results on the main thread
            withContext (Dispatchers.Main) {
                val rvDealsAdapter = DealsListRecyclerAdapter(deals, dealsViewModel)

                binding.rvDealsList.layoutManager = layoutManager
                binding.rvDealsList.adapter = rvDealsAdapter
            }
```

But this doesn't seem to work, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest looking into better serialization libraries than GSON. A lot of code samples do include it but it's an outdated reflection based solution that's been in maintenance mode for past few years and it has no official kotlin support.

Comment: Okay thank you @Pawel, I didn't know there were others, I will definetely check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a data class that matches your API response. From your response, I can see that it's a JSON object containing the list you want to extract. You should create your `Response` data class as follows:

```kotlin
data class Response(
    result: Boolean,
    offers: List<Offers>
)
```

Here, the result variable is optional. Then use this `Response` data class in your Retrofit API:

```kotlin
interface DealsService {
    @GET("getOffers/?API_KEY=$api_key&incremental=1&format=json")
    suspend fun getOffers (): Response
}
```

Hope it helps!